# where is the 2003 Wiper Relay on a 2003 honda accord?

Tags: honda, accord, windshield-wipers

I have a 2003 Honda Accord 3.0  Went to turn on wipers ( twice)... they tried to turn on but was frozen to windshield. I freed the wipers and scraped the ice off but then wipers don't even try to come on. It chicks at under hood fuse box. Power is at wiper motor. The garage replaced the switch, told me wipers turned on twice and quit.They say I have juice to the switch that I need a multi plex control box ( Underhood fuse box ) any suggestions or ideas ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Just a comment  because the info is from an unverified source. Look on the drivers side firewall near the brake booster.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot tell you exactly which one it is, but the car itself will tell you (if it exists). Here is what the under hood fuse box looks like:

[image: 2003 Accord Under Hood Fuse Box]

It is located on the right-hand side of the car (looking from the front) right next to the strut tower.

You can see on the inside of the lid of the fuse box that there is a diagram which tells you what is for what. The relays are the black and green larger pieces. The colorful ones with numbers on top are fuses. You may want to check these as well.

To get the lid off of the box, squeeze the four tabs at the same time and lift up.

Answer (score 1):

Use the diagram in the car. I just wasted an hour using the manual. In the LX the book has a "option" not listed under the hood the cover was correct. (Option) is an unistalled option Option is installed and you NEED it for the car to run.